# How to create unique ID column within groups, as variables in other columns are changing

Tags: r, grouping

I have troubles finding the correct code to use in the following issue:

I have a dataset (df) with Sections (rows) per ROV transects. I want to create a new ID column (i.e. a new grouping variable) based on the Sections and the variables Year and ROV. I want it to contain the first 5 sections (rows), then the next 5 and so on - until, the Substrate or ROV changes (the dataframe is ordered by Sections). So not every new ID will constist of 5 elements.

(I updated the dataset to better illustrate this issue)

```
dataframe<-
structure(list(Year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L), id = c("2021 ROV_3 1", 
"2021 ROV_3 2", "2021 ROV_3 3", "2021 ROV_3 4", "2021 ROV_3 5", 
"2021 ROV_3 6", "2021 ROV_3 7", "2021 ROV_3 8", "2021 ROV_3 9", 
"2021 ROV_3 10", "2021 ROV_3 11", "2021 ROV_3 12", "2021 ROV_3 13", 
"2021 ROV_3 14", "2021 ROV_3 15", "2021 ROV_3 16", "2021 ROV_3 17", 
"2021 ROV_3 18", "2021 ROV_3 19", "2021 ROV_3 20", "2021 ROV_3 21", 
"2021 ROV_3 22", "2021 ROV_3 23", "2021 ROV_4 2", "2021 ROV_4 3", 
"2021 ROV_4 5", "2021 ROV_4 6", "2021 ROV_4 8", "2021 ROV_4 9", 
"2021 ROV_4 11"), ROV = c("3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), Section = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 
11L), Mud = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Course = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), Lopheliaframe = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0), Bedrock = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ID = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I managed to make the ID with this code, but from ID 6 to 7, the error in the code is visible. I want it to not change ID when at least one of the substrate types stays the same.

```
dataframe%>%
  mutate(subgroup = rep(LETTERS, each = 5, length.out = n()),
         .by = c(ROV, Year,Mud,Course,Lopheliaframe,Bedrock)) %>%
  mutate(ID = consecutive_id(ROV, Year,Mud,Course,Lopheliaframe,Bedrock, subgroup) ) %>%
  select(-subgroup)
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R, you can try the code below via `ave`

```
transform(
    dataframe,
    ID = cumsum(ave(seq_along(Year), Year, ROV, Substrate, FUN = \(x) seq_along(x) %% 5) == 1)
)
```

which gives

```
   Year ROV Section     Substrate ID
1  2021   2       3           Mud  1
2  2021   2       4           Mud  1
3  2021   2       5           Mud  1
4  2021   2       6           Mud  1
5  2021   2       7           Mud  1
6  2021   2       8           Mud  2
7  2021   2       9           Mud  2
8  2021   2      10           Mud  2
9  2021   4       1       Bedrock  3
10 2021   4       2       Bedrock  3
11 2021   4       3       Bedrock  3
12 2021   4       4       Bedrock  3
13 2021   4       5 Dead Lophelia  4
14 2023   4       6 Dead Lophelia  5
15 2023   4       7       Bedrock  6
16 2023   4       8       Bedrock  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer based on comment and question edits.

```r
library(dplyr)

dataframe %>%
  mutate(subgroup = rep(LETTERS, each = 5, length.out = n()),
                        .by = c(ROV, Substrate, Year)) %>%
  mutate(ID = consecutive_id(ROV, Substrate, Year, subgroup) + 10) %>%
  select(-subgroup)
#>    ROV Section                      Substrate Year ID
#> 46   4      34                     1. Bedrock 2021 11
#> 47   4      35                     1. Bedrock 2021 11
#> 48   4      37 2. Bedrock with sediment cover 2021 12
#> 49   4      38 2. Bedrock with sediment cover 2021 12
#> 50   4      40 2. Bedrock with sediment cover 2021 12
#> 51   4      41 2. Bedrock with sediment cover 2021 12
#> 52   4      43 2. Bedrock with sediment cover 2021 12
#> 53   4      44 2. Bedrock with sediment cover 2021 13
#> 54   4      46 2. Bedrock with sediment cover 2021 13
#> 55   4      47 2. Bedrock with sediment cover 2021 13
#> 56   4      49 2. Bedrock with sediment cover 2021 13
#> 57   4      50 2. Bedrock with sediment cover 2021 13
#> 58   4      52 2. Bedrock with sediment cover 2021 14
#> 59   4      53                     1. Bedrock 2021 15
#> 60   4      55 2. Bedrock with sediment cover 2021 16
#> 61   4      56 2. Bedrock with sediment cover 2021 16
#> 62   4      58 2. Bedrock with sediment cover 2021 16
```

Comment: In fact, having a second look, this code  jumps over Sections to then pick the next element of 5, having the same Year, ROV and Substrate. But I want it to stop from change to change if this makes sense.  so no ID vector should look like this: 1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2. Instead I want 1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4. I'll try to share my dataset ....

Comment: Hi @Mona, I edited this answer to match the new `wanted_result` data frame in your question.

Comment: Thanks! It works well on my subset above, but strangely in my real data (over n>4000) i sometimes discover it only picks 4 consecutive Sections into one ID group.... Any chance I can share an entire dataset here?